# Counting columns that are not PK - Cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra, column-oriented

So I'm running with the problem of not being able to select a count of rows in my table.

My problem is: "Get the most reserved book in a library"

The model I created:

```
CREATE TABLE library_reservations (
     book_isbn bigint,
     book_title text,
     book_publicationdate date,
     reservation_date date,
     reservation_addinfo text,
     PRIMARY KEY(book_isbn)
);
```

The query:

```
SELECT book_isbn, book_title, COUNT(reservation_date) 
FROM library_reservations 
GROUP BY book_isbn;
```

I really feel like I got my modeling wrong. The table was an adaptation of PostgreSQL tables. So how can I properly get the count of reservations for each book? What shoud be my PK in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Cassandra does not have a GROUP BY function.

A possible solution would be to maintain a second table with a counter.

[Here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html) you can find some more info regarding counters.

In your particular case, when a new reservation is made you will have to update also the counter table info.

Another thing to have in mind is that tables in Cassandra are designed to satisfy a certain query.

Comment: Yes, I understand about the tables being design after queries, I'd have to rethink about all my table modeling (it was a mistake to directly translate the tables from PostgreSQL to Cassandra). About the counter table, would I have to create a funcion so that whenever I insert into the reservation table, it increases it by one? Are there triggers on Cassandra or can that be done in a different way?

Comment: The counters can only be incremented or decremented. Also, for a counter you cannot set a particular value (for instance reset in to 0 - one way to do it would be to read the value and decrement the counter with that value. Be aware that this operation might not be successful since the counter can be changed between your "reset" operations. ). There are triggers available in Cassandra. Still I would recommend to use batches.

Comment: indeed, Cassandra now has "Group By", but it could be only applied inside partition: http://abiasforaction.net/cassandra-query-language-cql-tutorial/

Comment: Regarding counters - they aren't necessary precise, you may get discrepancy when using them